# PHP - Function to remove character and concatenate another (aka converting relative to absolute url)

Tags: php, phpbb3

I have a phpbb external script which outputs a relative url

(like `./forum/viewtopic.php?f=xx&t=xx`),

but for making an rss feed I need the absolute url

(`http://example.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=xx&t=xx`) to use.

My question is: How could I make this?

I suppose it should just be a string function, to replace the first dot and then concatenate the `http://example.com` before it, but I don't have enough php skills to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply replace your `./` with the hostname.

```
$url = str_replace('./', 'http://example.com/', $url);
```

Comment: So, just this? The final result would be `$absurl = str_replace('./', 'http://example.com/', $url);` ?

Comment: Thank you so much mate! After the time limit to approve the answer is gone, i will do!